# Give boolean field a css class

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Unlike Charfield() or others where we can implement `first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextArea(attrs={'class'='something'}))`, how can we or is it possible to give a CSS class to a BooleanField. Tried looking into documentations and tutorials but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

The default widget for a `BooleanField` is a `CheckboxInput`. I don't see why doing the same thing would not work! Have you tried overriding the `attrs` attribute of the `CheckboxInput` widget? Like:

```py
your_bool=forms.BooleanField(
    widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'something'}))
```

Also, **be careful**: it's a dict you are passing to `attrs`, and you wrote `'class'='something'` while it should be `'class':'something'`.